# Is there any Node.js lib for SQL(esp. postgres) sharding?

Tags: postgresql, node.js, sharding

Sharding is not an issue when using Mongo or something like this.

Are there any solutions for sharding classical SQL bases, especially PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sharding on SQL DBs is a very app specific kind of thing. Not sure just how practical a library like the one you're describing could be. Mongo does offer auto-sharding but it doesn't mean it's going to always work for every scenario. Sometimes you will need to roll out your own solution based on your app's logic.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail of what you mean by "sharding" (and it does mean different things to different people), it's hard to give much of an answer beyond: Yes.  That said, you might want to look at [Greenplum](http://www.greenplum.com/) and [Postgres-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/).